# Programmatically switching CoreData between CloudKit and local storage

Tags: macos, core-data

I followed a tutorial and wrote a little app that uses CoreData.  I decided to try switching it to use CloudKit.  That was easy!  But then I wanted to go back to using local storage, and got "Store opened without NSPersistentHistoryTrackingKey but previously had been opened with NSPersistentHistoryTrackingKey".  This seems to come up often, but I haven't seen any actual solutions.

So how can I programmatically switch between the two persistent stores?  Anyone know?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I found my own answer, eventually.

```
  persistentContainer = NSPersistentContainer(name: "DBModel")
  let description = persistentContainer.persistentStoreDescriptions.first
  description?.setOption(true as NSNumber, forKey: NSPersistentHistoryTrackingKey)
```

for the non-CloudKit version.